# How to convert below code to accept input in one line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

```
stu_dict = {raw_input():[float(raw_input()),float(raw_input()),float(raw_input())] for i in xrange(int(raw_input()))}
print stu_dict
```

For the above code, Fox is the key, all three values are stored in a list (value)

i/p:
1
3
4
5
fox

```
o/p :
{'fox': [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]}
```

How to change above code, to accept  fox 3 4 5 in one line?

Note: All the solution given so far, I am aware of those, What I wanted was
taking fox 3 4 5(On same line) from input directly(without storing in string) and put directly into key, value pair of dictionary(value here is a list with 3 values).

Comment: does list always contain 3 values ? And what is the first line of input specifies (1 in your example ) ?

Comment: Yes, 3 values always, 1 means, I am giving 1 set of input(like key and value),@DineshSuthar

Answer (score 1):

If values for list are provided in single line, then use this-

```
>>>stu_dict = {raw_input(): map(float,raw_input().split()) for _ in raw_input()}
1
3 4 5
fox
>>>stu_dict
{'fox': [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]}
```

And if you are providing the input as described in question, then use this -

```
>>> stu_dict = {raw_input(): [float(raw_input()) for i in xrange(3)] for _ in raw_input()}
1
3
4
5
fox
>>> stu_dict
{'fox': [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]}
```

Comment: @bhansa : No, this doesn't, my input format is fox 3 4 5(String with key and list of values), not any other given here.

Comment: Are you giving your input like this `fox 3 4 5` one line at a time, then you need to update your question. It doesn't state that.

Comment: @bhansa I have already mentioned that, check this line "How to change above code, to accept fox 3 4 5 in one line?" I mentioned again in note now.

Answer (score 0):

Take your input in as a string and `split(" ")` and [`map()`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) or loop through it. Check the below example.

In the below example you can more than three number followed by "fox" or anything else.

**Example:**

```
stra = "fox 3 4 5"
dicta  = {stra.split(" ")[0]:list(map(float, stra.split(" ")[1:]))}

print dicta # {'fox': [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]}
```

Comment: I don't want to store input in string, I can't split direct through raw_input(),split()?

Comment: Yes @Nexus you can do that just iterate over your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split()` method of strings to split the input string :`'3 4 5'` to a list of strings `['3','4','5']`. And use `float()` function to convert these into integer values. -

```
>>> stu_dict = {raw_input():[float(x) for x in raw_input().split()] for _ in raw_input()}
1
3 4 5
fox
>>> stu_dict
{'fox': [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]}
```

Comment: you can also use [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) instead of looping through.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
l = input('Enter stuff: ').split()
stu_dict = {l[0]: [float(i) for i in l[1:]]}

{'fox': [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]}
```

Just make sure you enter it in string format:

```
'fox 3 4 5'
```